# wp_localize_script & wp_enqueue_script not working in front end

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Here is my code snippet :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/myajax.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 );
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

My problem is when ever i use that ajax_object it won't work. Also myajax.js file won't load to the site. But works fine in Admin panel.

Why that enqueue script & localize script not working in front end ?

Comment: If the file is not in the sourcecode of the frontend, please be sure your enqueue-function is not placed in a conditional (like is_admin). Can you confirm this?

Comment: what action hook do you use to enqueue the scripts? you should be using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action on the front end.

Comment: @Milo `wp_head` works as well (`wp_enqueue_scripts` is better)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. But actually enqueue script is not at all my problem. I could have added that to the header manually. My problem is Ajax request not working. Getting this error in console.

ReferenceError: ajax_object is not defined
$.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {

Comment: @JitheshKt - you couldn't add it to the header manually, as your localize call would fail because your `'ajax-script'` handle wouldn't exist. so have you used the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action or not? update your question to show the full code you've used to enqueue and localize.

Answer (score 1):

May be try get_template_directory_uri() instead of get_stylesheet_directory_uri(),
if your js file is in your theme, it should work frontend.

little help I know^^

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference

Comment: It does make a difference.